# Determine next in sequence when many patterns visible

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, puzzle

In a sequence given to find the next number that follows what happens if we can see 2 different ways to produce the next number? Given that the approach is based on inductive reasoning, unless the sequence is some specific well known math sequence how do we choose which is the most sensible choice?
Example:
If we have:

$3, 6, 18, 36, 108, 216, X?$

We could claim the following:

1. Since each number of the given sequence above is exactly divided by the 2 previous ones i.e. 18 is divided exactly by 6 and 3, 36 by 18 and 6, 108 by 36 and 18 and 216 divided exactly by 108 and 36 then $X=432$ since it is exactly divided by $108$ and $216$
2. Since we have $6 = 3*2, 18 = 6*3, 36=18*2, 108=36*3, 216=108*2$ then $X=648=216*3$

Is there some reason (2) is more valid than (1)?

Comment: I don't understand $1.$.  Lots of numbers are divisible by two given integers.

Comment: @lulu The 2 previous numbers of the sequence

Comment: If #1 is valid, the next number could be any multiple of $216$, including $216$ itself.

Comment: @Jim  What does that mean?  $72$ is divisible by $36$ and $18$, so why did you skip that one?

Comment: @player3236: But $1$ is not part of the sequence

Comment: @lulu: I did not skip it. It was not given as part of the sequence

Comment: Please state *exactly* the rule that $1$ is meant to express.  In a way that determines the next number uniquely.  As it stands, it's too vague to make sense out of.

Comment: @lulu: Updated the post. Is that clear now?

Comment: Not at all.  if you provide two integers $a,b$ (the last two numbers of your sequence, for example) then there are infinitely many integers divisible by both of them.  How do you choose which one to place next in the sequence?  Imagine you are writing a computer program to do this.  You could easily do that for rule $2$, but not for rule $1$.

Comment: @lulu: That is my question. I am not in favour of 1 vs 2. I was trying to undestand if in these sequence questions based on induction we can get multiple valid choices or not. May be this one to me it seemed a valid choice i.e. that I can see that each number in the sequence is divided exactly by the 2 previous ones is the pattern we need to determine the next number. I didnt think that due to the fact that there are other numbers that divide them breaks the pattern

Comment: As I say, $1$ is not a rule at all.  It is an observation regarding the sequence, but it does not enable you to generate subsequence terms.  But, generally speaking, of course it is possible to come up with multiple rules for a given starting sequence.  $\{3,5,7\cdots\}$ could be the odd numbers, or it could be the prime numbers (or lots of other things).  No way to tell.

Comment: @lulu: I think an elaboration of your comment is what I am looking for as an answer. I.e. (a) why is an observation in the sequence problematic (or does not suffice) to base the next term on (b) what can you do to make the "best" choice among multiple patterns

Comment: There is no "best" answer.  Informally, people tend to prefer clean, elegant rules to more elaborate ones, but that's obviously subjective. In a test or contest situation, you can generally imagine that whoever set the problem is after some short, easily described rule.  But if you encounter the sequence in some other way, you can't make that assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The most sensible choice

Unless you define exactly what you mean by sensible, the question you're asking isn't well-defined. The Fibonacci sequence is as good as any sequence starting like $\{1,1,2,3,5,8,13,-9383948,...\}$. In your case, $X$ can be absolutely any number and there would be no objective rule for ranking the options.

You can create a particular definition of sensible. For example, you could say "If it's an arithmetic or geometric sequence, those are sensible choices". Then you could use that rule to distinguish different options. But then your question answers itself: to rank the options you need to create a subjective rule to do that. The validity of your rule is again, subjective.

Comment: By sensible I mean if there is some convention on e.g. to pick the choice that has so and so characteristics

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to have conventions of these. Some sequences are sensible in some contexts, while in others contexts they aren't. My personal choice would be "If it's in oeis.org, then it's a sensible choice". But that would differ from your choice or a third person reading this. Again, unless you personally define sensible, all possible options are equally sensible.

Comment: @Jim Forgot to add you in the previous comment, sorry. I also want to point out that there are some quite interesting rules you could make to define sensible. Something like "The length of the shortest program that generates the sequence" in a particular programming language/turing machine. But then you're restricting yourself to that particular rule. And that rule may produce rankings that would be "unintuitive" for a person. So you always end up with inconveniences, no matter what you end up choosing.

Comment: `If it's in oeis.org, then it's a sensible choice".` what is `oeis.org`?

Comment: @Jim a website that compiles interesting Integer Sequences for research purposes (and other purposes as well), with formula, historical context and facts about it. www.oeis.org

Comment: Wasn't aware. Seems it is an existing sequence! http://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C6%2C18%2C36%2C108%2C216&language=english&go=Search